# writing python functions in salt-stack states

Tags: python, salt-stack

Writing saltstack code, I find myself wanting to manipulate the data structures from the pillar in ways that are easy in python and rather cumbersome in jinja.  At first it seemed that python-salt integration is easy enough, but I haven't found the details on how to do it.

What I want is to put something in `salt/foo/init.sls` akin to this:

```
{% for key, value in my_function(pillar['one_thing'], pillar['another_thing']) %}
    # declare some states parameterised by key and value
{% endfor %}
```

where `my_function()` is simply a python function that expects to receive two dicts (what I pass from pillar) and returns another dict.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe interesting: [custom execution modules](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#custom-execution-modules). Maybe you can also achieve what you've asked for - let me know if you can use the return value inside of the loop :)

Answer (score 3):

By default salt supports different [renderers to write state files](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/)
One of them is just [plain python](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.py.html), all you need to do is to start your file with proper shebang, implement `run` method and return the same dict that you would when using default `yaml` renderer:

```
#!py

def run():
  return {"state_id": {
    "cmd.run": [
       {"name": "ls -al"}
     ]
  }}
```

As an example you can look at this state [describing redis orchestration](https://github.com/kiemlicz/envoy/blob/master/salt/dev/redis/server/cluster/_orchestrate/orch.sls)

Comment: Oh, very cool, I'd missed that in my saltstack learning curve thus far.  But ... it seems that what I want requires a python-rendered _pillar_ sls, which in turn means that the `__pillar__` variable is not available.  When I try python-rendering in state modules, I find I can't use the resulting rendered structure the way I would use pillar data.  Am I confused?

Comment: You don't describe your problem fully. First of all: keeping logic in pillar seems like terrbile idea - pillar is even defined as **static** data. Second did you see: [best practices](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/best_practices.html)? There is a concept of _map.jinja_ file that can help you aggregate twisted pillar data. Third: salt supports [external pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/external_pillars.html), you can write your own with python

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the @lakier's answer and information you provided in its comment. State files are simply data structure generators, and salt use renderer pipes to decide how to produce data structures.

The default is `jinja` to `yaml`, which means `jinja` finish its jobs and the result is piped to `yaml` which then does its job, its represented as `jinja | yaml`. You can use this pipe to [compose renderers](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/#composing-renderers) and connect multiple renderers in a series as per your liking.

Here is a [full list of renderers](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/#full-list-of-renderers) that you can use for reference to compose and create custom renderer, for instance, `#!jinja|py`

There is also a [renderer function in slsutil](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2017.7/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.slsutil.html#salt.modules.slsutil.renderer) execution module which can be used to write sls in `python` syntax, or any syntax you want, and pull it into `jinja`,

**Example,**

```
map.sls

#!py
def run():
    apache = __salt__.grains.filter_by({
        ...normal map here but as a python dict...
    }, merge=__salt__.pillar.get('apache:lookup'))
    return apache
```

it can be accessed from any other sls file. The following is a usage example in Jinja,

```
{% set apache = salt.slsutil.renderer('map.sls') %}
```

You can also render directly from command-line using slsutil,

```
salt '*' slsutil.renderer /path/to/file
salt '*' slsutil.renderer /path/to/file.jinja 'jinja'
salt '*' slsutil.renderer /path/to/file.sls 'jinja|yaml'
salt '*' slsutil.renderer string='Inline template! {{ saltenv }}'
salt '*' slsutil.renderer string='Hello, {{ name }}.' name='world'
```